Maven-shade 3.5.2 + Flyway 10.12.0 (for HSQLDB 2.7.2 by API) doesn't work (JavaFX app.)
Flyway 10.12.0 (for HSQLDB 2.7.2 by API) doesn't work with maven-shade-plugin 3.5.2
v9.22.3 OK - 1 dependency : flyway-core
v10.12.0 NOK - 2 dependencies : flyway-core+flyway-database-hsqldb
Flyway relative issue
It works in development.
The error with the fat jar is the same as in development without flyway-database-hsql dependency :

FlywayException catch for flyway.migrate() : No database found to handle jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/toMyDb
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/toMyDb
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.(DriverDataSource.java:158)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.(DriverDataSource.java:96)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.setDataSource(ClassicConfiguration.java:1093)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.dataSource(FluentConfiguration.java:626)
    at fr.bla.utils.DatabaseMigration.configure(DatabaseMigration.java:23)
    at fr.bla.MyMain.initializationAsynchronousTask(MyMain.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:507)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1491)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2073)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:2035)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:187)
2024-04-29 13:38:00,898 ERROR f.s.s.MyMain [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Error in splash screen initialization virtual thread : org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/toMyDb
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/toMyDb
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1807)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:507)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1491)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2073)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:2035)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:187)
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/toMyDb
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.(DriverDataSource.java:158)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.(DriverDataSource.java:96)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.setDataSource(ClassicConfiguration.java:1093)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.dataSource(FluentConfiguration.java:626)
    at fr.bla.utils.DatabaseMigration.configure(DatabaseMigration.java:23)
    at fr.bla.MyMain.initializationAsynchronousTask(MyMain.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)

Flyway code using API :
 Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
    .dataSource(
        databasePath,    // as jdbc:hsqldb:file:...
        JVMApplicationProperties.getDbUser(),
        JVMApplicationProperties.getDbPassord()
     )
     .locations("classpath:" + ApplicationPaths.getDATABASE_MIGRATION_PATH())
    .baselineOnMigrate(true)
     .load();
 flyway.migrate();

Maven-shade configuration :
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${shade.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <transformers>
            <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>fr.bla.Launcher</mainClass>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <artifactSet>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin</exclude>
                <exclude>org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin</exclude>
                <exclude>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin</exclude>
                <exclude>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin</exclude>
                <exclude>org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api</exclude>
                <exclude>org.mockito:mockito-core</exclude>
                <exclude>org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter</exclude>
                <exclude>org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-plugin</exclude>
                <exclude>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin</exclude>
                <exclude>org.testfx:testfx-junit5</exclude>
                <exclude>org.hamcrest:hamcrest</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </artifactSet>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

@PiersWilliams here are my depedencies and versions when it's OK
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.13.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>22</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>22</javafx.version>
    <javafx.maven.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.7.2</hsqldb.version>
    <logback.version>1.5.6</logback.version>
    <shade.version>3.5.2</shade.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.32</lombok.version>
    <flyway.version>9.22.3</flyway.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>${flyway.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>

@jewelsea my first script V1_0__create_base.sql :
CREATE TABLE software (
softwareuuid UUID PRIMARY KEY,
currentversion VARCHAR(128),
lastversion VARCHAR(128),
createdat TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
updatedat TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);


It would be helpful for diagnosis to see your pom, or the section of it, that introduces the dependencies on flyway, flyway-database-hsqldb, etc

@PiersWilliams I edited my content ^^ *** When it's ok v9.22.3 flyway-core *** When it's not v10.12.0 of flyway-core and flyway-database-hsqldb (same version)

Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/toMyDb -> database migration tools won’t work without a database.

@jewelsea My first script create the database and the second make the inserts, I edited my content ^^

Regardless, flyway is complaining that the database doesn’t exist.  Does the database exist?  Is the database file in the location you specify? Can you access it using that JDBC url jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Users/toMyDb from another tool? Also, I don’t see any database creation script in your question, though I may have missed it.

Ok, see you added the script subsequently.

As of version 10.0.0, Flyway has abandoned the use of Java reflection in favor of the Service Loader.
The Service Loader allows you to dynamically load implementations of Flyway interfaces, such as database drivers, naming strategies, etc.
This transition to the Service Loader was driven by performance and compatibility issues encountered with the use of Java reflection.
So this tag is needed with Maven Shade :
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${shade.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <transformers>
            <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>fr.bla.Launcher</mainClass>
            </transformer>
           <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
        </transformers>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

Source found from Google code comment

I am facing same issue, but my project is a gradle project :)
Please help.

I got it working with the shadow jar plugin. https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow
